# Handling multipart/form-data in an HTTP request

Tags: html, c++, http, httprequest, multipartform-data

I implemented a HTTP server using the Linux socket API and one of the features I created is file transfering.

The problem I encouter is when I try to transfer png/jpeg files. After writing the binary file data, the file is corrupted and it can not be opened. For PDFs for ex. it works perfectly.

This is the way I process the HTTP request:

First I receive the request using the following function. Here I pass the buffer I received to the HTTPrequestsHandler:

```
template <typename T>
void server::printReceivedData(class acceptedSocket<T> *socket)
{
    T buffer[1025];

    int acceptedSocketFD = socket->getAcceptedSocketFileDescriptor();

    while (true)
    {
        ssize_t bytesReceived = recv(acceptedSocketFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

        if (bytesReceived <= 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Receive failed! "
                      << socket->getError() << "\n";

            std::string file = __user->getFileInQueue();

            if (!file.empty())
            {
                 addToFileTable(file.c_str(), 0);

                __user->clearFileInQueue();

                if (send(acceptedSocketFD, "HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nLocation: /index.html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", 65, 0) == -1)
                    std::cerr << "Failed to send response.\n";
            }

            break;
        }

        std::cout << "\n____________________________________________________________\n\n";

        buffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';
        std::cout << buffer;

        HTTPrequestsHandler<T>(buffer, acceptedSocketFD, bytesReceived);
    }

    close(socket->getAcceptedSocketFileDescriptor());
    delete socket;
}
```

In the HTTPrequestHandle function I forward the buffer to the correct route function (in this case the **/addFileRoute**):

```
int user::addFilesRoute(const char *buffer, int acceptedSocketFileDescriptor, ssize_t __bytesReceived)
{
    if (findString(buffer, "filename="))
    {
        fileName.clear();
        path.clear();

        path = "interface/storage/";

        const std::string t_buffer = std::string(buffer);

        std::regex fileNameRegex(R"(filename=\"([^\"]+)\")");
        std::smatch match;

        if (std::regex_search(t_buffer, match, fileNameRegex))
            fileName = match.str(1);
        
        path = path + fileName;

        addFileInQueue(fileName);
    }

    std::ofstream file(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.write(buffer, __bytesReceived);
        file.close();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here I write the file data in a file with the correct filename.

All the files I add are succesfully written to a file on my computer, but the image files are the ones that won't open.

**addFileInQueue** = function that prepares the filename to be pushed into the database

**filename** = global variable that holds the filename for the current HTTP request

**path** = global variable used to save the file at the correct location

I tried diffrent aproaces to format the file data. One was to remove all the headers that are extra from the request, but this would break everything.

!!! Keep in mind that buffer has chunks of 1025 bytes of data not the hole request

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: The shown code is incomplete and fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for a [mre]. I am noticing several things in the shown code that are nearly certain to be completely incorrect, but this cannot be stated authoritatively without a [mre], so I'll refrain from doing so. Please keep in mind The Golden Rule Of Socket Programming that states: "`send()` does not guarantee that all requested bytes to send will be sent, and `recv()` makes absolutely no guarantees, whatsoever, about what was received".

Comment: You are confusing byte buffers and C style strings. These are completely different. You cannot write a binary file such as jpeg using C-style strings and `operator<<`.

Comment: This is my first attempt to learn socket programming. How can I make sure I receive or send all the data?

Comment: A socket is a stream. "All the data" is just all the data until the stream closes. To get all the data of a specific piece of the stream, such as a request, or a part of a multipart message, or whatever, you need to know where that piece ends. In HTTP, the length of the payload is normally sent in the headers, you need to parse them. If it's a MIME entity, the length is in the MIME header of the entity. If it's an HTTP request with no payload, you may have to find where the headers end, that is, find the `\r\n\r\n` sequence.

Comment: Okay I will do just that. I saw in the HTTP request the headers wiht diffrent specifications but I did not think of using them.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue:

1. I Modified the **addFileroute** function to write the data as **uint8_t** type directly (I will get rid of the **char *buffer** and just recast it locally)

```
int user::addFilesRoute(const char *buffer, const uint8_t *byteBuffer, int acceptedSocketFileDescriptor, ssize_t __bytesReceived)
{
    if (findString(buffer, "filename="))
    {
        fileName.clear();

        const std::string t_buffer = std::string(buffer);

        std::regex fileNameRegex(R"(filename=\"([^\"]+)\")");
        std::smatch match;

        if (std::regex_search(t_buffer, match, fileNameRegex))
            fileName = match.str(1);

        addFileInQueue(fileName);
    }

    FILE *file = fopen("interface/storage/temp.bin", "ab");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(byteBuffer, sizeof(uint8_t), __bytesReceived, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file!\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

2. I wrote the data into a **temp.bin** file and after the request is received I process it. (at the end I remove the **temp.bin** file)

```
int server::formatFile(const std::string fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file("interface/storage/temp.bin", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream outFile("interface/storage/" + fileName, std::ios::binary);

    if (!file.is_open() || !outFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening files!" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::string boundary = "------WebKitFormBoundary";
    std::string contentStart = "Content-Type:";

    bool foundBoundary = false;

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        if (!foundBoundary && line.find(boundary) != std::string::npos)
        {
            foundBoundary = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (foundBoundary)
            if (line.find(contentStart) != std::string::npos)
            {
                std::getline(file, line);
                
                while (std::getline(file, line))
                {

                    if (line.find(boundary) != std::string::npos)
                        break;

                    outFile << line << std::endl;
                }

                break;
            }
    }

    file.close();
    outFile.close();

    if (remove("interface/storage/temp.bin") != 0)
        std::cerr << "Failed to removed temp.bin!\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```